# Injecting EJB into servlet via remote interface

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

I am reviewing some Jave EE 6 code and having doubts about its correctness:

```
@WebServlet
public class FooServlet {
  @EJB
  private transient BarRemoteInterface bar;
}

@Remote
public interface BarRemoteInterface {
}

@Stateless
public class BarBean implements BarRemoteInterface {
}
```

- I am wondering if that is true that the `transient` keyword does not make any sense as the injected proxy will not be serialized. (Or will be, but without effect?)
- I think that it would be more effective if we didn't inject the remote interface as that uses pass-by-copy parameter passing. Instead we'd rather inject the EJB with `@EJB BarBean` so that it's automagically generated (?) local interface will be used. Am I right?
- In this case even the `@EJB` could be replaced with `@Inject` as that is more general

Can you comment on my thougths if they are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering if that is true that the transient keyword does not
>   make any sense as the injected proxy will not be serialized. (Or will
>   be, but without effect?)

Transient is not needed. The EJB spec says the remote proxies must be serializable. If you want, you can have your interface extend Serializable.

> I think that it would be more effective if we didn't inject the remote
>   interface as that uses pass-by-copy parameter passing. Instead we'd
>   rather inject the EJB with @EJB BarBean so that it's automagically
>   generated (?) local interface will be used. Am I right?

Right, `@Remote` is essentially 'pass-by-copy' (not really, but this is close enough). Some application containers can optimize this anyway. You should only use `@Remote` if you're actually remoting. And you should avoid remoting at all costs. SOA-like architectures are slow and notoriously impossible to scale out. Just stick with `@Local` unless you have a damned good reason not to.

> In this case even the @EJB could be replaced with @Inject as that is
>   more general

Yep, feel free to `@Inject` your EJBs. Your JEE6 container (TomEE, JBoss7, GlassFish, etc) will be able to figure this out. As a matter of fact, you should ask yourself, do I really need an EJB at all? Can you accomplish your task with pure CDI? EJBs are only useful if you have to worry about transaction semantics, otherwise just use CDI.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Nice answer. Sometimes `@Remote` is a must (e.g. if communicating between different EAR's). I've described this some time ago on my blog [here](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/communication-between-ejb-modules-in-the-same-application-server/). CDI are fine if you're not interested in instance pooling, transactions or timers (from the top of my head).

Comment: Thanks, especially in this case we have two EAR's, so finally it turned out that we need that @Remote. Anyways, I learned a lot from you guys, so thanks.

Comment: Try combining the ears and benchmarking with @Local. You'd be surprised at your performance increase. Then do the same thing and take a look at your garbage collection stats. :D Good luck, and you're welcome